# Can we know the Nature of matter because we are "made" of it?

Tags: ontology, reality

When we consider the world to be curved spacetime sparkled and specked with tiny elementary particles (which ultimately may turn out to be ultra tiny compactifications os space) then logically we are ourselves parts of spacetime containing elementary particles.

The question is often asked how the true Nature of reality looks like. For example:
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-03633-1

But what is asked is how reality realy looks from the outside.

What about the inside of Nature? What is inside spacetime and particles? Can we somehow know this because we are ourselves made up of it? I don't mean if we can know the physical laws to which stuff conforms (though this would be an interesting question too so any one who wants to answer this...). I mean the non-physical charge of matter. Which can give rise (if it is actually there) to feeling or consciousness.

So. I am not interested here in the knowing of states in the physical sense. I am referring to the internal state of affairs. Could this explain conscousness? Are there philosophers who say anything about this?

Comment: It's not really clear whatsoever you're asking. Obviously it's false in general that "x can know the nature of y because x is made of y". For example, a bronze statue cannot know the nature of bronze.

Comment: @aduh Thats because its dead material. The statue feels dead iside. But I feel alive. I expeience something alive in the inside of matter.

Comment: It seems doubtful to me that the statue has feelings, but in any event, your comment doesn't help to clarify your question. It seems like you're just making up qualifications as you go now, e.g. "If x I made of y _and "feels alive"_, can x know the nature of y?"

Comment: @udoh You turn it into a logical problem. I dont ask if it is logically true though. I ask if consciousness is due to some kind of "charge" inside of matter or if it is an uncherges process giving rise to consciousness. If so then consciousness could be what we eat. Litterally. Conscious veggies...

Comment: I won't press this anymore, but your question still isn't clear. (I'm not making points about logic, I'm just asking for clarity.) If you're just asking about what consciousness is or what it's relation is to matter...well, that's an enormous question that philosophers have been thinking about forever. It's hard to give an adequate answer here. Pick up a book on the philosophy of mind!

Comment: Its not hard to understand the mind. Its hard to understand that consciousness springs from dead matter. How can the massively coordinated neural activities involved in dreaming lead to a perceived reality of sound and vision  complete with experienced feelings? How can such a process give rise to color or forms seen in the color. I know the neural correlate of seeing a balloon ot whatever form. In the same region of the brain all external objects can be seen (litterally) as firing (or inhibiting) neurons patterns. Patterns of huge numbers of neurons firing in a correlated parallel way.

Comment: But how can I perceive color when it is just dead matter. Musnt it havesomething inside? A (non-electrical) charge?

Comment: The hard problem of consciousness is indeed hard.

Comment: @aduh Isnt it made much easier to understand if you assume some kind of non-physical stuff in matter? The neural patterns are easy to understand. The emergence of consciousness from these much less though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly. It looks like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net

A real problem is our intuition that 'true' always means getting to look behind the curtain - 'getting our homework marked by god'.
When we think hard though, we find 'true' isn't IN the 'facts', it is IN the whole situation of evaluating them; and never stands separately from that.

There is no objectivity that's *separate* to us, and our contexts. Objectivity is just reified intersubjectivity.

I like to say, it is not that there are minds and there is the world, but that there is only the surface of interaction between them, which is meaningfully real.

Comment: What do you mean with "yes, exactly"? That the infinite grid ìs the nature of reality? Would we  perceìve this reality due to a charge in it or can it be perceived without such a charge?

Comment: For specific models, Integrated Information Theory & OrchOR are proposals for how mind & world are built out of the same things. Modelling the state space of actions to be able to make highly statistically unlikely impacts, is such a hallmark of life we use it to look for alien life, and we know it ourselves, by doing it. Better models, wiser choices, more alive.

Answer (score 0):

It [has been proven](https://homepages.fhv.at/tb/tb/cms/index.html%3Fdownload=tbPHILSC.pdf) by Thomas Breuer that an observer from inside a system where he is properly contained, cannot know its full physical state, and as such, cannot make accurate predictions of its future.

One can make a link with free will here: an observer cannot predict oneself, regardless of how good physical theories he employs.

The proof is mathematical, by diagonalization, so it does not depend on particular physical theories.

Comment: I actually meant the inside, the content, the Nature of matter. But this is very interesting too. I can be in a physical state without knowing it. The knowing is a physical state. You will never be able to know the state of knowing. Unless its somebody else who is knowing.

Comment: @DescheleShilder and this is applicable to the universe as a whole. There will always consequences, not followed from the theory. Not predictable by theory. Universally valid theories are impossible.

Comment: I think we are on some common level. So to speak.:)